# how to edit JSON value using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jakarta-ee

i want have a value for a specific key may be nested value also like change value of key1 to value100 or key11 to value111.

```
{
                "key1": "value1",
                "key2": "value2",
                "key3": "value3",
                "map1" : {"key4":"value4",
                "key5":"value5",
                "key6":"value6",
                "map2" : 
                {
                    "key7":"value7",
                    "key8":"value8",
                    "key9":"value9",
                    "map3" : 
                    {
                        "key10":"value10",
                        "key11":"value11",
                        "key12":"value12"
                    },
                    "map4" : 
                    {
                        "key13":"value13",
                        "key14":"value14",
                        "key15":"value15"
                    }
                }
                }
                }
```

how to achieve this using javascript or jquery. please help me to find out the issue.

Comment: google it and you will get many helpfull feedbacks

Comment: Do you want to update the value of your json and then save it?

Answer (score 0):

If you stored that in a variable like

`var object = { *your JSON here*}`

you can access it like:

```
object.key1
```

to obtain the value of your key1

If you want to get those in map2, it would be:

```
object.map2.key7
```

e.g.

If you want to change values, just do

```
object.key = *value*;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just hold your json on javascript object and edit it.

```
var _j ={
                "key1": "value1",
                "key2": "value2",
                "key3": "value3",
                "map1" : {"key4":"value4",
                "key5":"value5",
                "key6":"value6",
                "map2" : 
                {
                    "key7":"value7",
                    "key8":"value8",
                    "key9":"value9",
                    "map3" : 
                    {
                        "key10":"value10",
                        "key11":"value11",
                        "key12":"value12"
                    },
                    "map4" : 
                    {
                        "key13":"value13",
                        "key14":"value14",
                        "key15":"value15"
                    }
                }
                }
                };

_j.key1 = "New Key1";
$('div').html(JSON.stringify(_j));
```

Here is working [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pvpd2ome/)